# Вывод данных из mysql в особом порядке

Tags: сортировка, php, mysql

В БД хранятся товары с трех складов (1,2,3) и с признаком наличия (0,1). Как отсортировать выдачу следующим образом:

Товар с 1 склада, товар со второго склада, товар с третьего склада
Товар с 1 склада, товар со второго склада, товар с третьего склада
Товар с 1 склада, товар со второго склада, товар с третьего склада

и так далее (все в наличии), а затем в том же порядке вывести товары не в наличии.

Упрощенно табличка такая (без лишних полей):

id, stock_id, available, title, price

1, 1, 1, Товар 1, 100.00

2, 3, 1, Товар 2, 520.00

3, 3, 1, Товар 3, 130.00

4, 2, 0, Товар 4, 275.00

...

12653, 1, 1, Товар 12653, 1200.00

Comment: ORDER BY title, stock_id
Не подходит?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению. Нужно чередование складов, а тут последовательная выборка получается. Сейчас реализовано через костыль с массивами, но как-то неизящно получается. Как бельмо в глазу :)

Comment: Я почему-то предполагал, что один товар может быть на нескольких складах. В таком случае данный order by должен был сработать примерно так, как вам требовалось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Залезла ваша задача мне в голову - решился все-таки найти ей решение. Сам я не большой программист и род деятельности далек от подобного, но Интернет ведь один для всех, там-то много велосипедов изобрели уже!  
Нашел вопрос, аналогичный вашему с [готовым решением](http://toster.ru/q/116761) и несколько его подправил (как мне кажется, под ваши нужды).

Запрос в итоге выглядит как-то вот так:

```
SET @a := 0;
SET @b := 0;
SET @c := 0;

SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *, @a := @a+1 as `num` FROM `inventory` WHERE `stock_id` = 1

  UNION
  (
    SELECT *, @b := @b+1 as `num` FROM `inventory` WHERE `stock_id` = 2
  )
  UNION
  (
    SELECT *, @c := @c+1 as `num` FROM `inventory` WHERE `stock_id` = 3
  )

) AS `tbl` ORDER BY `available` DESC, `num`, `stock_id`;
```

Недостаток в том, что `available` прерывает чередование, хотя от этого никуда не деться - товары не всегда присутствуют на всех складах, и рано или поздно один склад будет доминировать в каких-то позициях.

Да и вообще какая-то непонятка с выводом присутствует (на примере моего фидла):

1. Чередование начинается неправильно, идет (3), (2,3) (1,2,3) ... (1,2,3), об этом ниже.
2. Мне так и не удалось понять, почему `num` начинается с 10, смущает то, что возвращается ведь, как и положено, 30 строк, не меньше.
3. Опять же `num`, непонятно, почему `num=10` присутствует лишь раз, `num=11` - дважды дальше все верно - `num=12` и последующие.

Проблема ***№1*** это следствие остальных двух, это понятно. ***№2*** - как-то связанно с выражением `количества записей, деленных на количество складов`, т.е. логично, что верхний `SELECT` возвращает результат до трех запросов одновременно. ***№3***  - насколько понимаю, сразу выполняется последний запрос, потом выполняется два последних запроса, потом лишь выполняются все три запроса, а вот почему так, я не смог понять.

Впрочем у вас уже есть от чего отталкиваться, можете взять этот код и обратиться на более узкоспециализирующийся форум, помощью оптимизации/объяснения/доработки.  
Думаю, и у нас найдутся умельцы, поэтому я также прошу помощи у них - объяснить, что является причиной проблем ***№2***, ***№3*** стало очень интересно! А также подсказать, насколько эта конструкция правильная в плане быстродействия.

Кстати, вот рабочий [фидл](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22ecb/6).

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Мне главное было, чтобы натолкнули на верный путь, а тут такой развернутый ответ с фидлом — это удваивает мою благодарность. Дальше разберусь, надеюсь.

ПС: я тут новичок, пока лайкнуть ответ не дают, но исправлюсь позже. Надеюсь быть Вам таким же полезным в будущем.

Comment: @densmith, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

А так же не забудьте отписаться как решили задачу в конечном счете!

Comment: [Так](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed856/15) будет ровнее.

Comment: По факту тоже самое получается, первые данные выводятся не верно. Пример вашего кода, но с измененными входными данными http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5ae9/1

Comment: @jackrv, да, вложенные запросы все портят. Весь смысл в корректной нумерации строк. Можно двумя запросами делать, что-то типа:

    select 
      case inv.stock_id 
        when 1 then @a:=@a+3
        when 2 then @b:=@b+3
        when 3 then @c:=@c+3
        ELSE 0
      end as num,
      inv.*
    from inventory inv
      where inv.available=1
    order by num

и аналогично для `available=0`. В этом случае при большом наборе данных, можно получить значительный выигрыш в производительности.  
Впрочем, задача слишком специфическая, чтоб добиваться какого-то супер красивого решения...